# Access csv or xml files from API with RStats

Tags: r, api

I am trying to access data files via an API.

The data guide is here and I can be connected to the API but I cannot navigate my way to the underlying XML or CSV files

http://sem-o.com/documents/general-publications/SEMO-Website-Report-API.pdf

My code reads in the file location but I don't know where the data is, and looking at the size of the URL it doesn't contain the data.

```
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)
library(lubridate)
library(XML)

url  <- “https://reports.sem-o.com/api/v1/documents/static-reports/?DPuGID=BM026&Date=2019-04-30”
raw.result<-GET(url)
#cannot find the data files within the url
names(raw.result)
raw.result$headers
raw.result$content

data<-read_json(url)
View(data)
head(data)
content(data)

## This gets down to Resource Name Level
results<-xmlParse(data$items[[40]]$ResourceName)
```

I am sure this is something simple in the way I am calling the file so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

With help from a friend I was able to find a solution to this. The key was the fact that the reports were dynamic and using the rbind function.

```
queryParam <- paste0('StartTime=%3E%3D', startDate,'T00%3A00&
                  EndTime=%3C', endDate,'2020-06- 
17T23%3A59&sort_by=StartTime&order_by=ASC&page_size=5000')

dynamic_url <- paste0(service_url, '?', queryParam)

dynamicReportData <- read_json(dynamic_url)

dynamicReportDataClean <- bind_rows(dynamicReportData$items)
```